# Cannot login with old openid.org account any more

Tags: support, openid

I have not visited stackoverflow and related sites for some months (shame on me) and meanwhile either SO or my OpenID provider changed their software.

I have troubles logging in, because the URL I gave to SO (dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier) was http://user.openid.org/, but they authenticate me (openid.identity) as https://openid.org/user

I get "This is an OpenID we haven't seen on Meta Stack Overflow before" error. I was stupid enough not to register an alternate OpenID account, so account recovery does not help me. I did not have a very high reputation, but I like my nickname too much, so if there is any idea how could I get it back, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usernames on Stack Overflow are not unique; you can re-use your old name if you wish to register a new account (but if you email team@stackoverflow.com they **might** be able to do something; in either case you can register an account now so you can start using SO right away and they will merge them).

Anyways I guess one of the downsides of the OpenID technology is that if your OpenID provider goes down or changes you're screwed!

Comment: Great idea, thanks. Maybe it was not only me who has problems with my openid.org account and there is some generic solution that helps them all.

Comment: @Kop: you're not screwed; a moderator can add a new OpenID for you if your provider stops working and you don't have an alternate set up.

Comment: @Ether: I was talking in general. OpenID is meant to be used as a "one login, one password" for all the websites that support it. Other websites may not be so nice.

Comment: I guess one of the downsides of e-mail technology is that if you e-mail provider goes down or changes your're screwed. If you consider e-mail "business critical", you probably want to make a solid contract with your e-mail provider or do the e-mail hosting yourself. Two similar options are available for those who consider OpenID business critical ;)

Answer (score 5):

Interesting, this appears to be a global change on their end, so I did this across all sites:

```
update Users
set OpenIdAlt = 
   dbo.RegexReplace(OpenId, 'http://(.+)\.openid\.org/', 'https://openid.org/$1')
where 
  OpenId like '%.openid.org/' 
  and OpenIdAlt is null
```

That should sort any users who have only this form of OpenID as the primary.

Answer (score 2):

Mail team@stackoverflow.com with your user details and another OpenID URL. If you can convince them that you are you, they'll fix you up!

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will try it.