# Unable to login using openid.org openid provider

Tags: support, login

Reason: openid.org's SSL cert has expired as of Sept. 17 2010.
I have tried to reach openid.org a few times but no use.

My SO account is unreachable.

Now I have some interested employers sending me job opportunities at careers.stackoverflow.com but I am not able to view it.

Have sent emails to careers@stackoverflow.com and team@stackoverflow.com, waiting for a response since 2 days.

Anything else I can try in the mean time.

Comment: Was this resolved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot login with old openid.org account any more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46043/cannot-login-with-old-openid-org-account-any-more) (see Jeff's answer in particular)

Comment: Yes, it was resolved.