# My Openid.org account doesn't work on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, login

I've been logging into Stack Overflow with my Openid.org account for a long time, but it doesn't work anymore.

I tried to verify my account by logging into Openid.org just now. I was successful, and it seems my account is fine.

I tried the following URLs on Stack Overflow:

> openid.org/nanohe
>       http://openid.org/nanohe
>       https://openid.org/nanohe

I always get the error messages below:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> No OpenID endpoint found

I *do* received the recovery email in my email box including `openid.org/nanohe`. But followed the same openid URL link, I still can't log into Stack Overflow.

Can anybody help me? I appreciate your help.

[update]

> Someone requested a Stack Overflow account recovery for this email address. If this was not you, please disregard this email.
>
> As a registered user, you have the following credentials associated with your Stack Overflow account:
>
> openid.org/nanohe
>      https://openid.org/nanohe
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/users/215912/nano-he

Comment: @Marc Gravell. How to recover it? Or can I transfer my stack Overflow openid.org account data to my another new open ID bind with google.com?

Comment: Have you tried the account recovery options in stackoverflow? Also: can you point me at your stackoverflow user account?

Comment: (see my answer for updated info)

Comment: Yes, I Do tried the recovery options. I pasted my email content to my original post above. thank you.

Comment: That https isn't going to work with a borked certificate.

Comment: Related question (10k only): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69554/unable-to-login-using-openid-org-openid-provider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it is the root cause, but their SSL certificate has expired (18/09/2010) - #fail:1. This does not bode well..

Registering to test it; they sent me back my password in the confirmation e-mail - #fail:2

---

IMO, that openid provider is borked - most likely the SSL certificate is blocking everything else. Your meta account is enough to demonstrate ownership of your SO account, so my suggestion would be to add a second openid to replace this one. For example, myopenid or gmail. Gmail is *slightly* problematic, since it varies per-site (meaning: I can't simply clone the data between SO and meta.SO), but if you create a *new* SO account against a gmail I can merge the two.

Either way, yes we can recover your account.

Comment: Yes, I would like to generate another account bind with `myopenid.com`. <br>
Attached the information below <br>  http://stackoverflow.com/users/483960/nano-he    <br> nanohe.myopenid.com    <br>  Could you please merge to the new one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NanoHE - try now

Comment: It works quite well now. Thank you very much.